# From Shell: Delete all files with apostrophes

Tags: bash, shell, delete-file, delete-directory

How do I delete all files in a folder that has an apostrophe?

for example:

> Baird/'s Tunnel.jpg
>
> Bach/'s Birds.jpg
>
> This isn//'t good.png

I would like all those files deleted but anything that doesn't have an apostrophe to remain intact, like:

> this is good.jpg
> donotdelete.png

Comment: bash preferably or sh is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sh you could do

```
rm *\'*
```

Comment: This won't work for the examples given, since they have spaces.  Better: for fn in *\'*; do rm "$fn"; done

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` command:

`find . -name "*'*" -delete`

As @Bryan pointed in his comment, this will delete all files in the current directory **and all subdirectories**. If you don't want to descend the directories use:

`find . -name "*'*" -maxdepth 1 -delete`

which makes `find` stay in the current directory.

Comment: of course, without any other arguments this will delete all files in the current directory *and* all subdirectories.

Comment: That should be `-maxdepth 1` (`-depth` is for depth-first processing and doesn't take an argument)

Comment: @Dennis for some reason, on my mac `-depth 1` behaves like `-maxdepth 1`

Answer (score 0):

GNU find

```
find /path/ -type f -name "*[']*" -exec rm {} +;
```